# How do I disallow shared folder when user is not logged in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, network-shares, shared-folders

One of my customers has to sign very strict NDAs that force him to find a way to block file sharing and lock his office when he is not on the premises. He also has the companies quickbooks files located on this computer. He would like to have a way that would allow him to block sharing of the protected files when he is not there, but allow sharing of the quickbooks file at all times.

He does not want to move the quickbooks to another computer, of course if he is out to another location or even just out to lunch the secretaries can not do anything in quickbooks as the computer is shutdown. The way the NDA reads is that if he can block access to the files when he is not there then all is well. According to him his lawyer says that a "reasonable effort" for protecting the files must be made, so he wants the files protected and piece of mind but not Fort Knox of computing.

Is it possible to share a specified folder only when the local account to that folder location is logged in? Is it possible to turn on such a feature without effecting the quickbooks file which is located in the Public user directory?

Windows 7 Home Premium 64x for all computers that are supposed to be on the network (5), 1 is supposed to have shared access to the files when he is there, and 3 need access to quickbooks at all times.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you set up the secured files in a folder locked down with appropriate NTFS permissions (I don't know what those might be, but hopefully you can sort that out).

You could then simply create a batch file that is set to run on login, and another on logout:

On login:

`net share sharename="c:\path\to\share" /UNLIMITED`

And on logout:

`net share sharename /delete`